# Perform Matrix-Like calculation on a master table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a master table like

**CityName, Month, Temperature**

A,Jan,20
....
A,Dec,1
B,Jan,30
....
Z,December,12

I would like to generate a differentiation table like

**iCity,jCity,Month,DifferentTemperature**
A, B, Jan, a.temperature-b.temperature
...
A, Z, Dec, a. temperature-z.temperature
.....

each row would loop through the rest row on a particular month in the master table.

What is the best way to do that? How did you come up an idea to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a [CROSS APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) Something like

```
SELECT
    M1.city AS iCity
,   M2.city AS jCity
,   M1.month
,   M1.temperature - M2.temperature AS final_temperature
FROM
    MASTER M1
    CROSS APPLY
    MASTER M2
    ON M2.month = M1.month
```

Comment: technically a CROSS - SELF JOIN.

Comment: Correct, I thought about that as I started to add a psuedocode sample and replaced the CROSS JOIN with the apply

Comment: This looks very neat. I will try to evaluate its performance. Thanks!